# How can I increase the scrolling speed of the Monocle e-reader library?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

We're currently using Monocle (https://github.com/joseph/Monocle) to build a book-reader application. The scrolling speed of the built-in Monocle.Flippers.Scroller is slow, especially when compared to native book applications. How can that be improved/sped up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it in `scroller.js`. There's code near the top that looks like this.

```
var p = API.properties = {
  pageCount: 1,
  duration: 300
}
```

Setting duration to 100 made it much faster, though we actually refactored it to use the k.speed constant (you can see the change we made [here](https://github.com/sguha00/Monocle/commit/55036895a1876b0e87ee8bb85d8e4b9f84b4792b)).